# replace string in regex

Tags: c#, string

hello everyone i have a question .
im trying to replace

```
private string StripHTML(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, "<a href='#' onclick='disposePanel();return false;'>Cerrar ventana</a>", String.Empty);
    }
```

but my return always contains the string , any clues? can be the '' ? or what i am doing wrong

```
<div id="head" class="header"><span class="closelink"><a href="#" onclick="disposePanel();return false;">Cerrar ventana</a></span><h1 class="certificado">Certificado de Asistencia en Viajes</h1><img class="header" src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/header-prevem-wtassist.jpg" alt=""></div><div><div class="cuerpo"><h3>Beneficios</h3><ul><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/concierge.png" alt=""><p>Línea de consulta</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/247.png" alt=""><p>Disponibilidad 24 horas</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/telefono.png" alt=""><p>Marcación gratuita</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/amabilidad.png" alt=""><p>Atención amable</p></li></ul><h3>Cobertura</h3><ul><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/medico-asistencia.png" alt=""><p>Atención médica por accidente o enfermedad no preexistente</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/evacuacion.png" alt=""><p>Traslado sanitario</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/medico-gastos.png" alt=""><p>Gastos médicos por accidente o enfermedad</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/asistencia.png" alt=""><p>Asistencia vial telefónica y auxilio de grúa dentro de México</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/cancelacion.png" alt=""><p>Cancelación e interrupción de viaje contratado</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/equipaje.png" alt=""><p>Demora o pérdida definitiva de equipaje</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/repatriacion.png" alt=""><p>Asistencia y repatriación funeraria</p></li><li><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/muerte-accidental.png" alt=""><p>Indemnización por fallecimiento accidental*</p></li></ul><h3>Tranquilidad</h3><div class="col-wrap"><div class="col-6"><img src="https://3.cdnpt.com/images/seguros/tranquilidad.jpg" alt=""></div><div class="col-6 sides-margin"><h4>Confía en los expertos</h4><p>Prevem Seguros es la aseguradora especializada en Gastos Médicos  y Accidentes Personales con sólida vocación de servicio a través de productos innovadores.</p><p> Forma parte de un grupo mexicano de empresas especialistas en diferentes ramos de seguros con 65 años de experiencia en el sector.</p><p>World Travel Assist con más de 10 años de experiencia en el sector de asistencia en viajes, conformado por un equipo, enfocado en servicio con una red internacional de asistencia, que no tiene restricciones territoriales.</p></div></div><div class="col-wrap"><div class="col-11"> <br><p class="small">*Esta cobertura será otorgada por Prevem Seguro, S.A. DE C.V., con quien WTA tiene celebrado un contrato para tales efectos.</p><p class="small">**El alcance de esta cobertura inicia 12 horas antes del vuelo operado por Interjet, durante el vuelo, la estancia en el destino con un máximo de 60 días y 12 horas después del vuelo.</p><p class="small">Aplican Condiciones y Exclusiones.</p></div></div></div><div class="footer"><div><div class="col-wrap"><h3>Contacto</h3><div class="col-6"><p>Para reportar un incidente ó hacer uso de la asesoría:</p><ul class="tel"><li>001 866-261-1935  |   En México</li><li>1-877-822-7386  |   En Estados Unidos</li><li>954-472-1895 | En Estados Unidos Cobro Revertido</li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: you need to escape your ()

Comment: Apart from the unescaped parentheses, you don't have any placeholders in your regex. Why aren't you just using `string.Replace()`?

Comment: can you provide an explanation of what type of HTML tags you're trying to get rid of? anything inside an anchor tag? or just a specific type of HTML as shown in your post?

Comment: maybe the problem is with something in the html i posted a moment ago ?

Comment: @Aominè  <span class="closelink"><a href="#" onclick="disposePanel();return false;">Cerrar ventana</a></span> i want to get rid this html of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Regex.Replace(input, "<a href='#' onclick='disposePanel\\(\\);return false;'>Cerrar ventana</a>", String.Empty);
```

Round parentheses must be escaped in order to perform an exact match. Normally, in regular expressions, they have a [different meaning](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). But honestly, I wouldn't use a regular expression to solve this problem and I would choose a `String.Replace` instead, since you are dealing with an invariant piece of text that doesn't need any particular pattern matching:

```
return input.Replace("<a href='#' onclick='disposePanel();return false;'>Cerrar ventana</a>", String.Empty);
```

Comment: i tried both solutions and still not working , keep returning the same string

Comment: @AlejandroDelossantos can we see the original text? Maybe what you are trying to remove does't match that piece of text.

Comment: nevermind , i paste "<a href='#' onclick='disposePanel();return false;'>Cerrar ventana</a>" in my function and worked , but still have the issue  when it comes with the complete string

Comment: That's what I would really like to see.

Comment: i put the complete html in the question @TommasoBelluzzo

Comment: Look carefully... you are looking for a tag with single quote attributes but in the original HTML it uses double quotes...

Comment: yeah but i cannot change the original HTML , and i cannot single quote the input.replace

Comment: Why not? `input.Replace("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"disposePanel();return false;\">Cerrar ventana</a>", String.Empty)` ... http://rextester.com/FEV1590

Comment: worked now , i had to add the <span> before the <a> , and start working .